# Filtering source in a Kendo Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have following Kendo template and MVVM binding. Source for this is template is viewModel that has `employees` inside it. The employees collection has 3 records in it. I need to display only those records for which the `IsSelected` property is true.

```
<!----Kendo Templates-->
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
      </tr>
</script>


employees: [
                    { name: "Lijo", age: "28", IsSelected: true },
                    { name: "Binu", age: "33", IsSelected: false },
                    { name: "Kiran", age: "29", IsSelected: false }
                   ]
```

**QUESTION**

How can we specify this filtering inside the template?

**CODE**

```
<head>
    <title>Template Filtering</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <!----Kendo Templates-->
    <script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
          <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
          </tr>
    </script>
    <!--MVVM Wiring using Kendo Binding-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            kendo.bind($("body"), viewModel);
        });

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({

            employees: [
                        { name: "Lijo", age: "28", IsSelected: true },
                        { name: "Binu", age: "33", IsSelected: false },
                        { name: "Kiran", age: "29", IsSelected: true }
                       ]
        });

    </script>

    <style>
        table, th, td
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="resultTable">
        <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: employees">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [KendoUI Check Boxes in a Grid: how to and some tips and tricks](http://onabai.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/kendoui-check-boxes-in-a-grid-how-to-and-some-tips-and-tricks/)
2. [Filter kendo ui grid with filed type object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276336/filter-kendo-ui-grid-with-filed-type-object)
3. [Filter Array|Object](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter)
4. [MVVM / Source and template binding](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/mvvm/source.html)
5. [how to run a function inside a template](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-run-a-function-inside-a-template)

Comment: Following is giving incorrect result -  http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Z86dq/4/

Comment: Working version - http://jsfiddle.net/jsonsee/Z86dq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the visible binding...

#### Use visible binding

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr data-bind="visible: IsSelected">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the first approach. But it is giving wrong result. Please test it by making following change - `{ name: "Kiran", age: "29", IsSelected: true }`.. But the second record is appearing in the result rather than the 3rd.

Comment: Both work, you can play around with it here: [http://jsfiddle.net/jsonsee/Z86dq/](http://jsfiddle.net/jsonsee/Z86dq/)

Comment: Can you please tell why this fiddle is giving wrong results - http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Z86dq/2/?

Comment: I think its a case where you are using JSFiddle incorrectly. The top left pane is for html (minus head/body tags), the top right pane is for css, and the middle pane is for JS. Also, you have a document.ready closure in  your template. You don't need that there.

Comment: ok, I took your fiddle and updated it for JSFiddle... its basically the same thing I posted before. [http://jsfiddle.net/jsonsee/Z86dq/](http://jsfiddle.net/jsonsee/Z86dq/)

Comment: Also, please note after making changes to the fiddle, you have to hit the 'Run' button.

Comment: Even your updated fiddle is giving incorrect result. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Z86dq/4/

Comment: I see what you mean, I reduced the answer to what I would do... try it and see.